# Averaging energy density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

Let we define energy density by,
$$E= a^2 \cos2 t +b^2 \sin2 t+ c^2 \cos 3t$$
where, $E=$ total energy, $a,b,c =$constants, and $t$ is the time.

I'm confused from someone's statement that `

> There may have been terms  in the above equation such as $cos(n t)$,(**n is any integer**) which has a zero time
>   average for full periods.

I want to get that how cos terms disappear from a energy equation when we do  time averaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a one variable function $f(t)$ with period $T$ the time average function is defined as

$$\frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^{T} dt f(t)$$

so what you need to compute is the following integral

$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt\cos(nt) $$

where $T$ is the smallest strictly positive number such that:

$$f(t+T)=f(t) $$

In this case $$T=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

$$\frac{1}{T}\int_{0}^{T}dt\cos(nt)=\frac{n}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi/n}dt \cos(nt)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0du \cos(u)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin(u)\bigg|_{0}^{2\pi}=0 $$